# How to get Display Enum value from string input

Tags: c#, enums

How do I get the value of an enum through input?

```
enum Planets
{
   Mercury = 0,
   Venus,
   Earth
}
```

I want something like when a user inputs a string for example I get the Enum integer Value of that input.

```
UserInput: Mercury

Value: 0
```

I did something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value: "+(Planets)UserInput);
```

and as you can guess it won't compile.

Comment: I think you want to parse the enum.
See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922930/net-custom-configuration-how-to-case-insensitive-parse-an-enum-configurationpro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var planet = (Planets)Enum.Parse(typeof(Planets), UserInput);
int planetNumber = (int)planet;
```

Comment: This returns The Name of that particular Enum, but not the value

Comment: Edited with cast to int.

Comment: If the user enters an invalid planet, this example will result in an exception. See my answer for a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to cast your input string into an enum of your choice. That can be done with `Enum.Parse(Type, String)`:

```
Planets planet = Enum.Parse(typeof(Planets), "Mercury")
```

Then you need to get the numerical value from the enum, which is a simple cast to integer:

```
int value = (int)planet;
```

Be careful with the first step: if the user inputs a string that is not valid, you'll get an exception which you'll have to handle. To avoid that you can use the `Enum.TryParse()` method which return a bool indicating the success of the action and pass the resulting enum as an out parameter.

```
Planets result;
bool success = Enum.TryParse<Planets>("Mars", true, out result);
if(success){
    Console.Write((int)result);
} else {
    Console.Write("no match");
}
```

Comment: The OP will find out soon enough that parsing user input requires validation.