# Can enum query parameters be case-insensitive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-7.0

When we migrated our application from .NET 6 to .NET 7, we found that enums used as query parameters had changed to being case-sensitive. We quickly started getting complaints from downstream systems, and had to fallback to .NET 6.

Is there a way to change whether query parameters are case sensitive?

For a controller like this

```
[ApiController] [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class EnumController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(MyValues myValue)
    {
        return myValue.ToString();
    }
}

public enum MyValues
{
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue,
    ThirdValue
}
```

This query-parameter will work in both .NET 6 and .NET 7:

```
?myValue=FirstValue
```

However this query parameter will only work in .NET 6

```
?myValue=firstvalue
```

In .NET 7 we get this error:

> The value 'firstvalue' is not valid
> "Type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
> One or more validation errors occurred

Comment: Have a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922930/net-custom-configuration-how-to-case-insensitive-parse-an-enum-configurationpro

Comment: @HassanMonjezi That's for the `.config` XML-based configuration system in .NET Framework - it isn't relevant to the OP's problem (which is ASP.NET Core enum value binding in .NET 7).

Comment: Please clarify: do you want enum binding to be case-sensitive or case-insensitive? (Your question title says you want case-insensitive, but your question body says you want case-sensitive behaviour).

Comment: I would like enum binding to be case-insensitive

Comment: BTW, as a stopgap you could use an IIS `<rewrite>`  rule to correct the casing by rewriting case-insensitive input requests to correctly-cased URIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled into the exact same issue, and it's related to the new [TryParseModelBinder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/142e078e3b524cf9f41f694bc7b3b8b5d25b3dda/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/TryParseModelBinder.cs) introduced in [.NET 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-7.0?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bind-with-iparsablettryparse-in-mvc-and-api-controllers).

The issue is fixed in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/46577 so if you update to .NET 7.0.5 it should work as intended and not be case sensitive.

Comment: If the links break at some point in the future you answer loses most of its usefullness. Try to avoid link only answers. Summarise what information the links provide.